# On bejeweled 3; diamond mine; how do you change from dollars to points?

Tags: bejeweled-3

I was playing Bejeweled 3 (diamond mine) and the points went away and changed to dollars. how do you change it back?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a setting that controls how your score is displayed in the Diamond Mine game in Bejeweled 3. I think that's just how they choose to show your score in the game (although in the Records section, scores are shown in points, and the Badges you earn are given for your score as points). The only options I see are global options for sound and video.